# How to write cts query using marklogic java api

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to run below query using the MarkLogic Java API

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("/abc/xyz"), 
cts:collection-query("/abc/xyz/pqr"))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [StructuredQueryBuilder](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html), the [`and()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#and(com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryDefinition...)) and [`collection()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#collection(java.lang.String...)) methods to construct the equivalent structured query to search for documents that are in both the collections.

```
// create the client -- this will change slightly in Java Client API 4.x
DatabaseClient client = 
    DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(host, port, user, password, authType);
// create a manager for searching
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();

// create a query builder
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
// build a search definition
StructuredQueryDefinition query = 
    qb.and(
      qb.collection("/abc/xyz"), 
      qb.collection("/abc/xyz/pqr"));

// run the search
queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a structured query, rather than a cts:query. They're very similar in expressiveness. The Java Client API includes a builder class for structured query, [com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html).

For details, see the following:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_70572
- http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/index.html
- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query